# Is there a reason for using Try/Finally with ExceptionThrown variable over Try/Catch

Tags: c#, coding-style

I was perusing the [.Net Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) and found this gem in [ButtonBase.cs](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/SP/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ButtonBase@cs/1/ButtonBase@cs) at line 408:

```
bool exceptionThrown = true;
try
{ 
    OnClick();
    exceptionThrown = false; 
}
finally
{
    if (exceptionThrown) 
    {
        // Cleanup the buttonbase state 
        SetIsPressed(false); 
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
    } 
}
```

Question being, what would motivate someone to use the `exceptionThrown` flag over just writing it as

```
try 
{
    OnClick();
}
catch
{
    SetIsPressed(false);
    ReleaseMouseCapture();
    throw;
}
```

Is it just stylistic or is there some side-effect I am missing?

Comment: Sounds like it would be ok to check for certain custom business related exceptions during the catch so you can do something else. This looks pretty much to be busting the stack for nothing. an empty try{} catch {} is worse than a throw for meaningfull reasons and you are just crushing the stack beyond that.

Comment: I think there is no difference between the two. However, if YOU write something like that, as code will change overtime, there will be some day that you need information from the exception, and you end up using catch. Small changes, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there are side effects to the `throw;` that will still remove stack trace information up through at least .Net 2.  I imagine this syntax was used to work around the implementation of `throw;` on early versions of the framework.

[This blog article](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2008/01/02/rethrowing-exceptions-and-preserving-the-full-call-stack-trace.aspx) gives two examples of how `throw;` is not equivalent to never catching an exception at all.

The question [Showing stack trace of exception that is re-thrown, rather than stack trace from throw point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364082/showing-stack-trace-of-exception-that-is-re-thrown-rather-than-stack-trace-from) gives a scenario whereby re-throwing the exception causes different operation in Visual Studio.

Comment: I should think this is the real answer. Avoid re-throw and so have accurate stack trace.

Answer (score 11):

The reason for this code is two fold.  Yes, a Greg mentions, it does not require rethrowing the exception.. but that's not really the reason.

The real reason is one of semantics.  Exceptions should not be used to handle control flow.  What this is doing is dealing with the fact that if an exception gets thrown within a button, It can leave the buttons visual state as "pressed".  This isn't really "handling" the exception.  This is merely correcting a visual problem in the event an exception is thrown.

This code does not care what the exception is, and it doesn't want to catch all exceptions because that's poor practice.  Further, the code is not doing anything with the exception.. it's just saying "Hey, if we got to the end of the function, then we're all good.  If we didn't, then lets reset the button state just to be sure".

So, this is not real exception handling, as such it doesn't catch an exception.  It just notices that an exception was thrown and does some cleanup.

EDIT:

This method might be less controversial, and make a lot more sense if it were simply renamed like this, removing any reference to exceptions:

```
bool cleanupRequired = true;
try
{ 
    OnClick();
    cleanupRequired = false; 
}
finally
{
    if (cleanupRequired) 
    {
        // Cleanup the buttonbase state 
        SetIsPressed(false); 
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
    } 
 }
```

EDIT:

To support my comment below, I wrote the following test program to test the scenarios:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan ts2 = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan ts3 = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan ts4 = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan ts5 = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan ts6 = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan ts7 = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan ts8 = new TimeSpan();

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    // throw away first run
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        try
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        catch
        {
            ts = sw.Elapsed;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        ts2 = sw.Elapsed;

        try
        {
            sw.Restart();
            try
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            finally
            {
                ts3 = sw.Elapsed;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ts4 = sw.Elapsed;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        ts5 = sw.Elapsed;

        try
        {
            sw.Restart();
            try
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            catch
            {
                ts6 = sw.Elapsed;
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ts7 = sw.Elapsed;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        ts8 = sw.Elapsed;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(ts);
    Console.WriteLine(ts2);
    Console.WriteLine(ts3);
    Console.WriteLine(ts4);
    Console.WriteLine(ts5);
    Console.WriteLine(ts6);
    Console.WriteLine(ts7);
    Console.WriteLine(ts8);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And I got the following results (I have split them apart to make them easier to read):

```
00:00:00.0028424
00:00:00.0028453
```

---

```
00:00:00.0028354
00:00:00.0028401
00:00:00.0028427
```

---

```
00:00:00.0028404
00:00:00.0057907
00:00:00.0057951
```

The last 3 show that when rethrowing the exception using `throw;` it does not simply pass the existing exception on, it has to recreate the exception and rethrow it, taking twice as long.

As we can see, there isn't a significant difference between catching an exception and not catching, but using a finally.  However, rethrowing the exception is where the cost comes in.

This is run in VS 2012 Update 3.

EDIT:

Timings without the debugger.  As you can see, rethrowing is still twice as expensive:

```
00:00:00.0000149
00:00:00.0000154
```

---

```
00:00:00.0000137
00:00:00.0000140
00:00:00.0000146
```

---

```
00:00:00.0000137
00:00:00.0000248
00:00:00.0000251
```

Comment: Either way, it's a nice, clever piece of code that avoids the stackwalk cost of a catch clause. But I'm a bit iffy on renaming the `bool` to `cleanupRequired`, since it hides exactly by what mechanism we came to know this. At some point, you can get a bit *too* clever, and the next thing you know, somebody's on StackOverflow asking everybody, "WTF were they thinking when they did *this*?" ;-)

Comment: That seems more of a stylistic distinction than a functional one. In fact, it seems like you are re-implementing the semantics of a catch just because of the name.  Other interop or exception prone code certainly doesn't use flags to implement cleanup.

Comment: @Mitch - I don't think it's stylistic at all.  OnClick() is likely execute user written code, so it could do pretty much anything.  While a catch all would work, it's extra overhead for no valid reason.  This code just notices that the OnClick call did not return normally, and does some cleanup.  It doesn't care what or how, so why catch something you don't actually care about?

Comment: @MystereMan, you seem to suggest that there is some requirement which mandates that `catch` statements handle an exception, when the ability to rethrow them allows them to be used in just this situation.  Besides, the question is whether there is a _functional_ difference, not a style or semantic difference.

Comment: Also, what is this "overhead" imposed by a catch?  Is it more overhead than the possible bugs introduced by 3 extra LOC and a confusing flag?  Beyond that, I _do_ care about the exception - perhaps not it's type, but I care that it happened.  Relying on the non-execution of a line of code seems far more semantically aberrant.  The semantics of a finally block is that it "always executed, whether an exception occurred or not" whereas the catch is "used to catch exceptions that occur during execution of [try] block"

Comment: @Mitch - It's extra overhead because you have to rethrow the exception, which cause a second stack unwinding.  and Yes, it does.  I've tested it.  rethrowing the exception doubles the amount of time it takes to handle the exception.

Comment: @MystereMan, I believe your performance tests are testing VS, not C# - if I run your tests without a debugger attached, the increase in time is less than 20 microseconds.  See http://ideone.com/4E6BNa for what I would consider to be a more appropriate comparison (< 1% change measured).  But all perf tests are really not the point when the code is harder to read and performant with try/catch.  "Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute."

Comment: @Mitch - i'm not sure what it is you think your code is testing, but it's not correct.  Your doCleanup swallows the exception, and does not rethrow it.  In fact, You have no rethrowing of an exception in there at all.  Yes, running in a debugger is slower, but it's just illustrating the example.  When I run my code without debugger, it's much faster, but still the rethrow is twice as slow.  You can certainly argue that readable code is important, but you were arguing that there was no performance overhead.  That's simply wrong, it's twice as expensive to rethrow.

Comment: @MystereMan, nice catch on the catch error.  See http://ideone.com/7IceAf for the updated test.  I am not saying there is no performance impact, but that a performance micro-optimization is irrelevant in a button handler for an exceptional case given the decrease in readability.

Answer (score 8):

If you use try, catch like that an exception has to be thrown twice. With try, finally only one exception is thrown so it is <strike>a lot</strike> more efficient<strike>, especially</strike> if this code gets called often.

Comment: If the **exceptional** code is called **often** then it isn't exceptional anymore. Performance optimizing the error code path is usually a poor return on investment.

Comment: +1 nice answer, was one of the first one to upvote ... but I've seen my shares of optimizations & I have to tell you that, this is not true - the code is not 'a lot more efficient' actually it's only about 10-15% more efficent which means that there is optiomaztion in place & there actually isn't 2 stack walks happening as one would think on throwing the exception again in the first example. [Here is a test app](http://ideone.com/mn84X3) looks like it's a tiny tiny bit faster to use the finally trick, so tiny in fact that it's not worth writing the obfuscated code with finally clause.

Comment: so what we are talking about is likely 2-3 additional instuctions being executed on the `try/catch` example which considering that there is an actual method call inside the real example it would be unoticable optimization & can be ignored as perfromance improvment ... more or less but still +1 for the **nice catch**

Comment: It's not just about performance. Claiming to handle exceptions, but not actually handling them, also complicates debugging since the debugger cannot know in advance, when the exception is thrown, whether it will be handled. If your custom `Click` handler throws an exception that you don't know about, and you're debugging your program, you generally want to know *exactly* what's going on. Avoiding the double `throw` helps here.

Comment: I almost always have my debugger set up to Stop on Thrown Exceptions. That way, if there's an exception that gets thrown on almost every run, I try to factor it out by using a non-throwing alternative. The Framework used to have quite a few APIs where you couldn't test for a non-exceptional exception without wrapping a `try...catch` block around it (e.g., the `Parse()` family of methods), but the situation's improved greatly over the years (e.g., `TryParse()`).

Answer (score 1):

Well, one reason I can think of is (in future) adding the need for catching specific exception, while maintaining the same cleanup behavior. Consider following examples:

```
try 
{
    OnClick();
}
catch(System.SomeSpecificException ex)
{
    Handle(ex);
    throw;
    // now, we're missing the cleanup
}
catch
{
    SetIsPressed(false);
    ReleaseMouseCapture();
    throw;
}
```

vs.

```
var exceptionThrown = true;
try 
{
    OnClick();
    exceptionThrown = false;
}
catch(System.SomeSpecificException ex)
{
    Handle(ex);
    throw;
    // whoa, I added specific handler, but cleanup is called anyway!
}
finally
{
    if (exceptionThrown) 
    {
        // Cleanup the buttonbase state 
        SetIsPressed(false); 
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small note: `OnClick` is a virtual method. It is expected to be overridden by user-written code, which can throw arbitrary exceptions. The code as written expresses the semantics of "clean up from the mess made by those who overrode this method".